# General method to convert enum to List<T>

Tags: c#

Here's a "weird" question:

Is it possible to create a method where in it will convert whatever enum to list. Here's my draft of what I'm currently thinking.

```
public class EnumTypes
{
   public enum Enum1
   {
      Enum1_Choice1 = 1,
      Enum1_Choice2 = 2
   }

   public enum Enum2
   {
      Enum2_Choice1 = 1,
      Enum2_Choice2 = 2
   }

   public List<string> ExportEnumToList(<enum choice> enumName)
   {
      List<string> enumList = new List<string>();
      //TODO: Do something here which I don't know how to do it.
      return enumList;
   }
}
```

Just curious if it's possible and how to do it.

Comment: What should the list contain?

Comment: @Habib: I believe that this is not a duplicate. Because the user can just pass as parameter either `Enum1` or `Enum2`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: If possible, the key and value of the enum chosen.

Comment: This is duplicate unless your question is "how to express `ExportEnumToList(<enum choice> enumName)`> genrecally or via reflection".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Enum.GetNames( typeof(EnumType) ).ToList()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx

Or, if you want to get fancy:

```
    public static List<string> GetEnumList<T>()
    {
        // validate that T is in fact an enum
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).ToList();
    }

    // usage:
    var list = GetEnumList<EnumType>();
```

Comment: +1: Nice way of writing generic method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> ExportEnumToList(<enum choice> enumName)    {
List<string> enumList = new List<string>();
//TODO: Do something here which I don't know how to do it.
foreach (YourEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnum ))){
    enumList.Add(item);
}
return enumList;
```

}